# Div hidden (under) bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 3 to design my website. I defined a navbar-fixed-top.

I needed to define a div fixed top superposed on the navbar for a search form.

I used z-index (=16777271 to be sure) to put the search div over the navbar.

It works well on my Firefox browser (with any width) but when i try it on my phone, the search div doesn't appear.

Here are some parts of my code :

NavBar :

```
<div class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-rt-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/toto/"><img src="/toto/img/logo.png" alt="toto" style="max-width:120px; margin-top: -15px;" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-rt-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/favorites"><i class="fa fa-history"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="/login"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

HTML for search div :

```
                                                                        <div class="fixed-search">
<input name="query" value="" id="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Find ..." autocomplete="on" maxlength="255" type="text"/>
```

CSS for search div :

```
.fixed-search {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:16777271 !important;
  top: 8px;
  height: 35px;

}

.fixed-search-btn {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:16777270 !important;
  top: 8px;
  height: 35px;

}
```

I search for a solution on Google but I didn't find any discussion about this problem.

If someone have a solution to solve this problem or can explain from where it come, I am very interested.

Thank you, Best regards,

Raphael

Comment: You can use inline form in the navbar itself ! So why did you use another div for the search bar  ?

Check this one with the search box http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted. I defined the problem differently : I want to put the search query in the fixed navbar, out of the sidebar. So my real question was : Can i put an input out of the form ? The answer is Yes. You can define the  properties of your input equal to the form id. That's all and it works very well.

Thanks for help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have achieved.

[image]

For this just replace your navbar markup along with the input with the code I provided below and also importantly remove your styles you have explicitly applied for `fixed-search` & `fixed-search-btn`. All these are unwanted codes. Just replace the `navbar` code with the below code, bootstrap & font-awesome will take care of the rest across all browsers.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/toto/"><img src="/toto/img/logo.png" alt="toto" style="max-width:120px; margin-top: -15px;" /></a>
    </div>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group fixed-search">
        <input name="query" value="" id="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Find ..." autocomplete="on" maxlength="255" type="text"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default fixed-search-btn">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/favorites"><i class="fa fa-history"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/login"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i can't do it this way, else i would did it. I defined a complex (advanced search) in a side bar and i want the search input of this side bar to be positioned on top of my page. That's why i can't use the navbar-for class. Moreover I can't put the all page as form because there are others forms in my page. Do you have another trick ?

Comment: Regarding the forms, you could just use a class say `fixed-search-form` to only the `<form>` you want and use the styles on that class. Regarding the complex structure, the sidebar information was important and should have been mentioned at the first. I will see what can be done taking that into consideration now.

Comment: It seems to appear fine on my phone. Chrome + Android. Can you please mention your phone specifications.

Comment: I tried on samsung S4 and S4 mini (Android) with Chrome and default browser. Same results. Yesterday I tried to define the all navbar in the sidebar, with the simple structure as you told, it gaves me the same result : OK on computer, but this time, the all navbar does not appear on phones. I supposed it comes from the sidebar but i can't explain it :[

Comment: May be you can take a screenshot (**Volume down button + Power button** for you) and attach it here if you don't mind. Wouldn't take much time.

Comment: As you can see on the picture (http://i65.tinypic.com/xbmfx2.png), the navbar doesn't appear but the navbar form seems to be attached to the top of sidebar on phones.